# What could cause a Django based Facebook Page Tab to take 2 minutes to load?

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-page

I have a very simple web page that uses the Facebook Javascript API and is installed as a tab on a Facebook page. When the page is loaded, the only thing it does after calling the usual Facebook init code is to listen to `auth.authResponseChange` and then show/hide various elements depending on whether the user is logged in or not.

If I load this page, via http or https in an ordinary browser session, everything is fine. The page loads reasonably fast.

But if I load the page tab in Facebook, it hangs for about two minutes. Chrome tells me that this wait is due to 'waiting' for my page. But if I watch the access log, I don't see an access request logged until just before the page displays. So it seems like Facebook is masking what is really going on behind the scenes.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a ticket with Facebook, and they replied that this issue was due to my code and reproducible with any POST that contained a signed_response.

After much head scratching and experimentation, I found that adding the following two lines to the view that handles this page fixed it:

```
if 'signed_request' in request.POST:
    pass
```

So clearly Django 1.3.1 is holding the HTTP session open until you actually read some POST values. Ouch.